# Should I check in bootstrap/cache - Laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel, git, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I'm using **Laravel 5.8**, these 2 files often show up on my `git status`.

[image]

Should I add them to **.gitignore** ?

Comment: there should already be a `.gitignore` file in that directory that tells it to ignore the contents of that directory

Comment: @kyo remember to mark the answer as correct if it worked out.

Comment: you should close your question

Answer (score 9):

Add this line in your `.gitignore` file

```
bootstrap/cache
```

and then run

```
git rm -r --cached bootstrap/cache
```

`git rm -r` is used to untrack files in a Git branch. This command will remove the file from the staging area and also will remove the file from the repository next time you commit.

Comment: For me it was bootstrap/cache (without the leading /).

Comment: Yes if you're in root folder then you don't need to use `/`

Answer (score 8):

In the folder `bootstrap/cache` there should already be a `.gitignore` file containing the following lines:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

and it's this file that will fix your issue

Answer (score 3):

You should always `.gitignore` cache files, they're never meant to reach the actual production server.

So create a `.gitignore` file in the `bootstrap/cache` folder, and put the following two lines:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

Remember you might have to remove the files and git push before you can actually ignore them.

Comment: Will do. Thanks 